# How to queue incoming events in event handler while waiting for user's response

Tags: c#, .net, events, design-patterns

I use C#, .NET Framework 4.5, VS2015.

I implement an event handler for event (TcpRequest) that is fired by a black-boxed module.
My event handler call a private method that fires an event to client/GUI and waiting for user's response.
Meanwhile the black-boxed module keeps firing TcpRequest event. Somehow I need to queue the incoming events while waiting.
As soon as the user gives response for the first event, the queue can be "flushed".

Is there any design pattern or best practice for such case (**to queue while wait for user's response**)? Do I need to use **await** or something?

Following are my codes. Please feel free to modify them. Thank you in advance.

```
public void TcpRequestHandler(int id, CONN_INFO connInfo)
{
    if (SomeCondition)
    {
        var myArgs = new MyEventArgs()
        {
            Id = id,
            ConnInfo = connInfo
        }

        // this the way I tried and I know it is wrong,
        // because it always fires event without "waiting in queue"
        lock (_eventQueue)
        {
            _eventQueue.Add(myArgs);
        }
        FireEventToClient(myArgs);
    }
}

private void FireEventToClient(MyEventArgs myArgs)
{
    EventToClient(this, myArgs);
    if (myArgs.Continue)
    {
        // "flush" the event queue
        ...
        // do other things
        ...
    }
}

public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Id {get; private set;}
    public CONN_INFO ConnInfo {get; private set;}
    public bool Continue {get; set;} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your event **EventToClient** with return value and use the returned value for validation and flush the event queue

Comment: I want to know how to queue the incoming events correctly.

Comment: You mean you are developing a service between GUI and a black box module?

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it may help

public class TCPServer
    {
        private int _port;
        private TcpListener _tcpListener;
        private bool _running, _disposed;
        private BinaryFormatter _bFormatter;
        private Thread _connectionThread;
        private BackgroundWorker _bgwListener;
        private BackgroundWorker _bgwSender;
        private object syncobject = new object();
        private object syncsendmessageobject = new object();

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor - Initialises the TCPServer with the given port and a tcplistener. Starts a thread to monitor the message queue
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="port"></param>
    public TCPServer(int port)
    {
        try
        {
            this._port = port;
            this._tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
            this._running = false;
            this._bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Thread thread = new Thread(ReadQueue);
            thread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the tcplistener.
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_running)
            {
                this.MessageReceived -= TCPServer_MessageReceived;
                this._tcpListener.Start();                   
                this._running = true;
                this._connectionThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClientConnections));
                this._connectionThread.Start();
                this._connectionThread.IsBackground = true;
                this.MessageReceived += TCPServer_MessageReceived;
            }
        }           
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }        

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the tcplistener
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        if (this._running)
        {
            this._tcpListener.Stop();
            this._tcpListener = null;
            this._running = false;
        }
    }

    public bool Running()
    {
        return this._running;
    }

    public void StopListening()
    {
        try
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                if (this._running)
                {
                    this._tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient().Close();
                    _running = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Thread body for listening for client connections
    /// </summary>
    private void ListenForClientConnections()
    {
        try
        {
            while (this._running)
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    TcpClient connectedTcpClient = this._tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    this._bgwListener = new BackgroundWorker();
                    this._bgwListener.DoWork += _bgwListener_DoWork;
                    this._bgwListener.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                    this._bgwListener.ProgressChanged += _bgwListener_ProgressChanged;
                    this._bgwListener.RunWorkerAsync(connectedTcpClient);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// background worker listens to messages sent by clients. Categorises them based on messages/commands/applicationcommands/
    /// progress response etc..
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private TcpClient clientGUI = null;
    private Queue<string> messageQueue = new Queue<string>();
    private void _bgwListener_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)        
    {           
        TcpClient client = e.Argument as TcpClient;
        BackgroundWorker bgWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        if (client != null)
        {
            try
            {
                while (this._running)
                {
                    // Block until an instance Message is received 

                   string message = this._bFormatter.Deserialize(client.GetStream()).ToString();

                    if (message.Equals("GUI", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                    {
                        // Chek for first message from tcp client, if it is GUI then store it in a member variable, if you have multiple cleints then use a dictionary
                        clientGUI = client;
                    }

                    if(!clientGUI.Equals(client))
                    {
                        lock (syncobject)
                        {                   
                            messageQueue.Enqueue(message);                 
                        }
                    }                       

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Thread that continuously monitors the message queue for messages and 
    /// sends them to clients
    /// </summary>
    private void ReadQueue()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    TCPMessage message = null;

                    if (messageQueue.Count > 0)
                    {                          
                        lock (syncobject)
                        {
                            message = messageQueue.Dequeue();                               
                        }

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message) && clientGUI != null)
                        {
                            SendMessage(clientGUI, message);
                        }

                    }
                    else { Thread.Sleep(10); }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }           
    }


    private MessageReceivedEventHandler _messageReceived;
    public event MessageReceivedEventHandler MessageReceived
    {
        add { _messageReceived += value; }
        remove { _messageReceived -= value; }
    }

    private EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> _serverMessageSent;

    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> ServerMessageSent
    {
        add { _serverMessageSent += value; }
        remove { _serverMessageSent -= value; }
    }


    private void SendMessage(TcpClient client, TCPMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (syncsendmessageobject)
                _bFormatter.Serialize(client.GetStream(), message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }       
}
```